# How to get a sorted list from a list which contains many list that have already been sorted?

Tags: python, algorithm

For example, I have a list with many many elements

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8], ...]
```

each element has already sorted.

How can I get a list named `y` that is from `x`'s elements and sorted it?

Comment: What output do you want? please provide some output

Comment: Merge each pair of lists; repeat. (You can't get asymptotically better than that with comparison, or you could write merge sort that way.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#K-way_merging

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you should look into `heapq.merge`:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> lists = x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8]]
>>> list(heapq.merge(*lists))
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution without any library:

```
x = [[1,2,3], [3,4,5], [2,3,4], [4,7,8]]

print(sorted([item for sublist in x for item in sublist]))
```

Returns: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort use `sorted`,try this

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8]]
y = sorted(x)
print y
```

If you want to get all elements in sorted way,try this

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8]]
y = sorted([item for sublist in x for item in sublist])
print y
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a "merge" operation: just start with two lists and keep taking the element that is smaller; when one list is completed copy the eventually remaining elements from the other one...

```
def merge(A, B):
    result = []
    ia = ib = 0
    while ia < len(A) and ib < len(B):
        if a[ia] < b[ib]:
            result.append(A[ia])
            ia += 1
        else:
            result.append(B[ib])
            ib += 1
    # copy "tail"
    while ia < len(A):
        result.append(A[ia])
        ia += 1
    while ib < len(B):
        result.append(B[ib])
        ib += 1
    return result
```

If you have a collection of `N` lists just merge them in pairs and you will end up with half of them. Repeat until you get just one list.

Comment: I think that algorithmically, you can do better here... Specifically, consider the corner case where the list ranges don't overlap and the ranges are sorted in the way you want the -- `[[1], [2], [3], ..., [100]]`.  Your algorithm which is to merge them 2 at a time will produce `[1, 2]` which needs to be merged with `[3]`, then `[4]`, then ... At each point, you need to look at all of the numbers that you've already merged before you can start putting in the new data.  I think this leads to an O(N^2) merging time.  If you _know_ the mins from all of the lists, you can put them in a heap ...

Comment: (continued) ... In other words, the best solution (I think) is to put all the mins in a single heap.  pop/yield the global min.  put the next item from the list who had the min onto the heap. repeat until all of the items have been put onto the heap and then just pop out the rest of the heap items.  Unfortunately, this takes a good amount of book-keeping :-)

Comment: Merging in pair means going from `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], ...]` to `[[1,2], [3,4], [5, 6], ...]`, not keeping merging the same list with all the other ones.

Comment: Right, but then don't you need to keep merging the merged pairs until you only have one list left?  Isn't that what your last sentence says?

Comment: @mgilson: yes, but every element will be processed only O(log(n)) times; complexity of merge sort (implemented correctly) is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking about this offline ... If there are n sublists and k total items, I think your algorithm is O(k*log(n)).  I originally assumed this would look like:  `merge(merge(merge(a, b), c), d)` rather than `merge(merge(a, b), merge(c, d))`. The latter is more efficient as the number of sublists increases.  In any case, I think that the heap solution is still better in some cases.  The heap starts out size n (so each pushpop takes log(n)) but if sublists get exhausted, the heap can shrink which would lead to near O(n) performance in some pathological cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you some pointers.

First, define a function `merge(x, y)` that gets two sorted lists and returns a combined sorted list.

Then, run merge on couples

```
[merge(lst[i], lst[i+1] ) for i in range(0,len(lst),2) ]
```

This process should be repeated as long as the list has more than two elements, and if the number of elements is odd, append [] to it

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
import heapq
x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5],[2, 3, 4], [4, 7, 8]]
y = list(heapq.merge(*x))
```

Method 2:

```
import itertools
y = sorted(itertools.chain(*x))
```

Comment: You're better off using `itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)` (just to get in the habit)

Comment: @ mgilson ths for the tip